# How can we display MySQL table data in datagrid in vb 2008

Tags: mysql

I tried to display MySQL table data using data grid in vb2008, but could not do, can anyone send be the procedure.

Edit:

```
rs = db.Execute("select *from productentry")
        While Not rs.EOF
            ListView1.Columns(0).ListView.Items.Add(rs.Fields(0).Value)
            ListView1.Columns(1).ListView.Items.Add(rs.Fields(1).Value)

            rs.MoveNext()
        End While
```

I tried this code in vb 2008 but all the data are displayed in the first column only. Can anyone tell me how to display the codes in different columns

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you add the code to you question then we can see what you have done & advise on how to fix your problem.

Comment: I added the datagrid and ADOCDC , but could find the properties  to link the database

Comment: See this : http://www.vbtutor.net/lesson26.html - if that does not help add your code to the question - it doesn't display properly formatted in a comment.